# Change Unit Background Color on hover using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get a cell, within div table created in jquery, to change color when I hover over it and remain that color when the mouse leaves the cell.

I have tried adding a .hover command but when I add it the entire grid goes away.

Here is my code at JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davidtaylorjr/eemLsjg7/8/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
        $("<div>").addClass("unit").appendTo('#container');
      }
    }
  });
  
  $(".unit").hover() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "black");
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 192px;
  width: 192px;
}
.unit {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: The table is created by the jquery code, not in the html.

Comment: Ah ok, it's the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is correct aside from two syntax issues. Firstly, you need to provide a function to `hover()` to be executed when the `mousenter` and `mouseleave` events fire. Secondly, you have nested document.ready handlers which you should unwrap. With those fixed it works fine.

Note however that you can make a couple of tweaks to improve the logic. Firstly the nested loops are redundant as you append the same HTML in all iterations. You can make this a single loop. Secondly it's better practice to keep all styling in CSS, so you can simply use `addClass()` to change the background colour. Lastly, the `hover()` creates two events, of which the `mouseleave` isn't needed for your code, so you can use just `mouseenter` to make it more efficient.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = ''
  for (var x = 0; x < 16 * 16; x++) {
    html += '<div class="unit"></div>';
  }
  $(html).appendTo('#container');

  $(".unit").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('black');
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 192px;
  width: 192px;
}
.unit {
  background-color: white;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
}
.unit.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Also note that you can remove the loop altogether and use the `fill()` method of an array to create your `.unit` elements:

```
var arr = new Array(256);
arr.fill('<div class="unit"></div>');
$('#container').html(arr.join(''));
```

Note that this is unsupported in IE and Safari, although a polyfill is available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill)

Comment: Note, you could also use `.not()` to avoid calling `.addClass()` again if the element already has the `.className`; e.g., `$("#container").on("mouseenter", ".unit:not(.black)"`

Comment: @guest271314 that wouldn't have an effect here as the event handler is not delegated

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the background color of your element when the mouse enters, and subsequently unbind the handler (so the code will only execute on first `mouseenter` - as specified in your description)

```
$(".unit").mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "black");
  $(this).unbind('mouseenter');
});
```

jQuery mouseenter documentation for reference: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/#mouseenter-handler

Updated (and simplified for the sake of demonstration) fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eemLsjg7/9/